# index.html is not served when hitting /static/ location

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask

I'm following this [realpython article about running Flask on Ubuntu](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/). It is advised in the article to check if **nginx** has been configured properly by navigating to http://localhost:8000/static url. It gives me **404**.

If navigating the http://localhost:8000/static/index.html the *index.html* is served. I have tested it on both **Ubuntu Zesty** and **Trusty** and getting the same **404** result. Is it by design or is it a mistake?

Here's the config from the article:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask_project/static/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't say that.

In your configuration, port 8000 is served by gunicorn, not by nginx. nginx proxies to that port for URLs under / - *except* for /static/ which you have set to be served by nginx directly.

As the tutorial says, to see the static file you should go directly to the URL on the *default* port, ie 80: http://localhost/static/index.html.